# How to get Hasura Cluster Name from Hasura running in Docker Container?

Tags: docker, hasura

ive installed Hasura with the Docker Container.
To use the Hasura Authentication in my ReactNative App, i have to set the Hasura Clustername in my project.

I know you can find the Name with the hasura cli command `hasura cluster status` if you got the Hasura CLI Localy, but how i can pass this hasura command to the Docker Container to retrive the clustername, or is there an other way to find out the clustername from the docker image?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the **Hasura CLI** is not installed inside the docker container. So, the easiest way is to map the container's **Hasura** port (8080) to your localhost port and then run **Hasura CLI** from the local machine. Else, you will need to attach to the docker container and download to **Hasura CLI**

Command to start a container and map container's 8080 port to localhost's 8080 port (--rm deletes the container after stopping):

`docker run --name hasura --rm -p 8080:8080 hasura/graphql-engine:latest`

and now **Hasura CLI** will work towards localhost:8080 (careful so that this port is not used by something else)